# pl/sql block to display employees information

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
ACCEPT p_1 PROMPT 'Please enter the last name:'
DECLARE
v_last_name VARCHAR2(20) := '&p_1';
v_Hire_date person.hire_date%TYPE;
v_Job_type person.job_type%TYPE;
v_Job_status person.Job_status%TYPE;
v_pilot_type pilot.pilot_type%TYPE;
v_n number;
BEGIN
select count(*) into v_n from person
where UPPER(last_name) = v_last_name;
IF v_n != 1 THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_CHAR(v_last_name) || ' is not in the table. ');
--ELSE 
select UPPER(e.last_name),e.hire_date,e.job_type,e.job_status,
p.pilot_type into v_last_name,v_hire_date,v_Job_type,v_Job_status,v_pilot_type
from person e JOIN pilot p
ON (e.person_id = p.person_id)
order by last_name;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(RPAD('last_name',10) || RPAD('hire_date',10) ||
RPAD('Job_type', 30) || RPAD('Job_status',10) || RPAD('pilot_type', 20));
ELSE
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No output!');
END IF;
END;
```

I have written this code to display the employee information. The problem is in IF condition. It's not displaying the result.

RESULT : 
If I enter the user input last name as brown  it displays only this as below

> brown is not in the table.

Comment: the immediate cause is because you've commented out the 'else'.  But as MTO shows, you should not be using "if/else" for this in the first place.  Just assume you will get results, and handle the exception if you don't.

Answer (score 1):

> " If I enter the user input last name as brown"

Your question is slightly ambiguous, but if you are actually inputting the name in lower case (literally as *brown* ) then the problem is easy to diagnose:

Your WHERE clause casts the column value to upper case but not the input:

```
where UPPER(last_name) = v_last_name
```

This translates to `upper('brown') = 'brown', which will never be true,because`'BROWN' <> 'brown'`.

So, either opt for an exact match or apply the case conversion to both sides:

```
where UPPER(last_name) = upper(v_last_name)
```

Alternatively, perhaps you have more than one person called Brown? That would also show the no record message, which would be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

ACCEPT p_1 PROMPT 'Please enter the last name:'
DECLARE
  v_last_name  person.last_name%TYPE := UPPER( '&&p_1' );
  v_Hire_date  person.hire_date%TYPE;
  v_Job_type   person.job_type%TYPE;
  v_Job_status person.Job_status%TYPE;
  v_pilot_type pilot.pilot_type%TYPE;
BEGIN
  select e.hire_date,
         e.job_type,
         e.job_status,
         p.pilot_type
  into   v_hire_date,
         v_Job_type,
         v_Job_status,
         v_pilot_type
  from   person e
         JOIN pilot p
         ON (e.person_id = p.person_id)
  WHERE  UPPER( e.last_name ) = v_last_name;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
    RPAD(v_last_name,10)
    || RPAD(v_hire_date,10)
    || RPAD(v_Job_type, 30)
    || RPAD(v_Job_status,10)
    || RPAD(v_pilot_type, 20)
  );
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( v_last_name || ' is not in the table. ');
  WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'No output!' );
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but still i am able to see only one record. i need to display all the employees name.

Comment: Then change from using `INTO` to `BULK COLLECT INTO` and use collections for the variables then you can use a `FOR ... LOOP` to iterate over all the return values. Or else you can use cursors and loop over the cursor rows.

Comment: thank you i got it. can you tell me how to use DECODE for Job_Type. Job type as two FT and PT i want to make FT as Fulltime and PT as Parttime